# Xcopy - Trying to copy a folder with certain arguments to another location

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to xcopy certain folders from a directory of 5000 folders, that start with the number 9097*
Approx 2000 folders start with 9097.

```
for /f %%A in ('DIR /b /a:D') do (
    set temp=%%A
    set ID=!temp:~0,4!
    if !ID!==9097 xcopy  *!ID!* F:\%INPUT% /S /i
```

My problem is that when it finds the first folder starting with 9097, the code then goes and copies all contents of all the folders, I want it to only copy the 9097 folders. I understand why the code above is doing what it is doing but I can't seem to think of the way for it to just copy the folders and contents starting with 9097.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in (9097*) do xcopy "%%~fa" "f:\%input%\%%~nxa" /s /i
```

For each folder with a name starting with `9097`, `xcopy` from the full path of the source folder to the target inside a folder with the name and extension of the source folder.